# Return empty list of documents

Tags: vb.net

How do I create a if statement to check for a document for a case that is deleted or check if there is no document that exist and if? 
If there is no document found or the list is empty, I would like to return an empty list of documents and return nothing if the return is not a list.​

**My scenario:**

I have a method **GetDocuments** which can throw an Object Reference error when trying to get a document for a case event that is deleted or where no document exists.
I would like to fix my method to

1. Return an empty list of documents when document for a case event that is deleted
2. Return an empty list of documents when no document is found (exists)
3. Return nothing if the return is not a list.​

**Do I need to add if statement to check if the document exist or if there is a document list returned? I am not sure how to do it**

```
    Imports System.Xml
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

 ''' <summary>
    ''' Retrieve all documents associated to the spcified case event.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="aintCaseEventIntegrationID">The integration id value that identifies the case.</param>
    ''' <returns>An array of Document objects.</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <System.EnterpriseServices.AutoComplete()> _
    Shared Function GetDocuments(ByVal aintCaseEventIntegrationID As Integer, Optional ByVal ablnUsePrimaryDatastoreOnly As Boolean = False) As List(Of Document)
        Dim objDocumentsArray() As Document = Msc.Integration.Mncis.Library.v4.Document.GetForEntity(aintCaseEventIntegrationID, udtDocumentAttachedEntityType.CaseEvent, ablnUsePrimaryDatastoreOnly)
        Dim objDocumentsList As New List(Of Document)
        Dim objDocument As Document
        For Each objDocument In objDocumentsArray
            objDocumentsList.Add(objDocument)
        Next
        Return objDocumentsList

    End Function
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your asking about a review more or less. Please [**see**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) there. Also just a suggestion, turn `Option Strict On`... Another thing worth mentioning. You declare `objDocument` before the loop, but never assign that object to anything, but then add it to a `list`. It will be nothing at this point in that list. Why declare it in the first place, it may be fighting against your loop declaration. Your for each could be `For Each doc As Document In objDocumentArray`...

Comment: If you want to convert an array to a list, you can just call [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx). If the error happens because objDocumentsArray is nothing, just make an if statement.

Comment: I am not sure how to go about the if statement. This is what I need help with creating an if statement to check if there is a list and or if the document exist.

Comment: A function can only have `one` return type. Either return an empty list or `nothing`... and handle the return where you are calling it.

Comment: How to I modify the my function to return and empty list or nothing? Then I will handle the return where I am calling this method. I want to use **test** to do this

Comment: A simple if condition: `If objDocumentsList.Count > 0 Then Return objDocumentsList Else Return Nothing`... That's one way of many... But why not just return a list period and check it in the calling function... If there's a count your good otherwise you do not have anything...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is Nothing in your question. I can only assume it's objDocumentsArray.

```
Shared Function GetDocuments(ByVal aintCaseEventIntegrationID As Integer, Optional ByVal ablnUsePrimaryDatastoreOnly As Boolean = False) As List(Of Document)
    Dim objDocumentsArray() As Document = Msc.Integration.Mncis.Library.v4.Document.GetForEntity(aintCaseEventIntegrationID, udtDocumentAttachedEntityType.CaseEvent, ablnUsePrimaryDatastoreOnly)
    Dim objDocumentsList As New List(Of Document)

    If objDocumentsArray IsNot Nothing Then
        objDocumentsList.AddRange(objDocumentsArray)
    End If

    Return objDocumentsList
End Function
```

Don't prefix your variable with their type in vb.net. Instead of aintCaseEventIntegrationID just have caseEventIntegrationID .

Comment: This was written by someone else and I am just trying to modify it. You are right return nothing means that when objDocumentArray() does not have anything in it